# A question on sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $$u_n = \frac{\Bigl(1+\bigl(-1\bigr)^n\Bigr)+1}{5n+6}$$ Find the number of terms of the sequence $u_n$ which satisfy the condition $ u_n \in \Bigl(\frac{1}{100},\frac{39}{100}\Bigr)$

---

*My* *approach* :

First I considered n to a odd natural number . I got the following inequality

$$\frac{1}{100} < \frac{1}{5n+6} < \frac{39}{100} $$ Then considering n to be a even natural number : $$ \frac{1}{100} < \frac{3}{5n+6} < \frac{39}{100}$$

In both the cases I approximated the values of $n$, then found the number of odd and even natural number that lies within that range. My answer was 38. But the correct answer is 18. So please mention those range of odd $n$ values and even $n$ values , it will be very helpful for me and i can find where i did the mistake. And if there is a different approach to this question then please mention that too. I will be glad to know.

Comment: To the OP: to prevent your questions from consistently getting down- and close-votes, please add your thoughts. To the down/close-voter(s): tell the OP to add context instead of just downvoting!!!

Comment: Thank you sir. @RhysHughes. 

 If you all comment below, i will definitely correct myself. But please don't down vote the question.

Comment: you need to edit the question and add your thoughts on it or the down-votes will just keep coming...

Comment: Ok sir, I will surely add them too . Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Identicon I solved your problem here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872249/ If you want to see my solution undelete this topic and write your trying.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg i am editing that question too sir. I will show my work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*HINT*:
Consider odd $n$ and solve simple inequalities like: $$\frac 1 {100} < \frac 1 {5n+ 6} < \frac {39} {100}.$$

Do the same for even $n$.

Comment: I did the same. But my answer is different from the given answer . So can you complete it so that i can check . Please

Comment: and what's your answer? in that case you better show your work in question.

Comment: I edited my question , can you please check it.

Comment: i got the same answer and it seems to me that $18$ is a typo, should've been $38$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For $n=2m$ we get

$$\frac{1}{100}<\frac{3}{10m+6}<\frac{39}{100}$$
this becomes $$m<29.4$$
Can you proceed now?

Comment: Shouldn't the $\frac{99}{100}$ be $\frac{39}{100}$?

Comment: Just corrected!